# Can sleep be replaced by chemical supliments?

Tags: brain

If adenosine makes a person sleepy to rebuild chemicals in the brain, than is it possible to inhibit adenosine and externally produce and inject the needed chemicals?

Comment: There is not only one substance involved in sleep (which is a sophisticated process); orexins and others have a contributory role. How would you know what to inject without a more complete understanding of sleep and its function?

Comment: Also, rebuilding chemicals is not the only function of sleep: it is also a method to remove toxic wastes, relax the body, and (possibly) maintaining & creating memories. So, no SLEEP cannot be substituted with chemical supplements.